# Hibernate 3.2.5 with Play Framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am trying to use Hibernate 3.2.5 with Play framework 1.2.5

In Hibernate I am having two files:

1) cfg.xml file (containing the db config details **along with some additional properties**
2) hbm.xml file (containing the mapping between the java bean and the db table

For getting connected to the oracle 10g db, I am providing the db details in the application.config files like this and the connection is successful also when I start the server:

```
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.user=system
db.pass=tiger
```

I want to know Where will I place the hbm.xml file (for mapping details) and the cfg.xml file for the remaining properties other than db connecion details?

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the root directory of your application:

- the `hibernate.cfg.xml` must be placed inside the `app` directory
- the mapping files (the `hbm` files) where your models classes are defined, usually inside the `app/models/` directory

Inside your `hibernate.cfg.xml` the `mapping` attributes should be something like:

```
<mapping class="models.yourHmbFile1"/>
<mapping class="models.yourHmbFile2"/>
```

Btw, I find easy to use the [hibernate annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)  instead of the hbm - xml mapping. Easier to write and to mantain.

If you prefer to annotate your model classes, you can delete the `hbm` files and directly map your annotated classes in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

In the `application.conf` you've to specify the data you have already added:

```
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.user=system
db.pass=tiger
```

Also in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` you need to specify the connection data:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">...</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">...</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">...</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">...</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">...</property>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I also find easy to use annotations but this is not within the scope of this project, hence desperately willing but cant help :( Can you please let me know whether in this case I need to add the DB related details in the `application.conf` file or not? Once I get this reply, I will proceed trying out the same. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is nt it a repetition of same information (i.e. the connection details) in both the application.conf and the cfg.xml file???

Comment: Actually it's but in the project I developed time ago it worked fine, actually I can't do tests right now...

Comment: @Atropo I am using Hibernate in my Play (1.2.5) application. How do I handle the database connection pool? Through hibernate.cfg.xml or application.conf Or both produce the same result? Apologise if the question doesn't make sense.